# Android: How to check a modified status of image on web

Tags: android, image, performance

I'm developing an Image Manager in Android. It will always check images in servers to draw...

I use a Disk-cache to cache images in SDCARD, and i must refresh them by cycles for some minutes..

But, Performance is not good if always update non-changed files.

How to check a changed status of an image? I want only get changed-files...
Can get a hash-code of image? or check-sum code?

I thinked a soluton: create a XML file on server, that stores all hash-sum list...
But, it not possible... so, Images are stored in many many sites...

thanks!!!

Comment: http has a code for that. 304 (not modified) when making a request with if-modified-since header.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

- Attach a time stamp to each image every time it is updated/modified.
- On each refresh cycle, get only the time stamps of images and compare with timestamps of images on device.
- Only download images which have timestamps greater than that of the corresponding cached images.

This way, you'll only be downloading text data (very small in size) in each cycle and image downloading will only be done when it is necessary.

You can also wire up your backend server to respond to a REST API and return only the updated images. The decision on whether to handle the calculations and logic on client side or server side will need considerations of the tradeoffs involved and will depend a lot on your apps specific requirements.